# What is the default setting for continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication on Spring Security 4.x

Tags: spring-security

What is the default setting for the setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication() method on Spring Security's AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter? The javadoc summary at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/ says:

> By **default**, the filter chain will proceed when an authentication attempt fails in order to allow other authentication mechanisms to process the request. To reject the credentials immediately, set the continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication flag to false.

The documentation on the method http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html#setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(boolean) says:

> ... If false (the **default**), authentication failure will result in an immediate exception.

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the confusion but as these links saying its actually by default set to TRUE so to continue validating other included authentication filters. The implementation is :-

```
private boolean continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication = true;
```

Comment: I don't believe that's correct. The documentation on the method specifically says "if false (the default)". In other words, it's saying that the default setting is false which would cause an immediate exception. The summary implies that the default is true which would cause request process to continue. Please clarify if I'm reading this incorrectly.

Comment: And yes, you are correct about the concrete implementation, it is set to true in the source. I had read that earlier and missed the initialization value. Thanks for your answer.